# Precheck fields when I add a new post

Tags: plugins, php, functions, customization, categories

Precheck fields (like categery or custom fields) in new post based on user id.

Its possible to make this?

Comment: Which editor are you asking this question for? Classic editor? Block editor? Page builder?

Comment: Classic editor. But automatically checked based on user id. Or something similar.